# How can I prevent my computer from interfering with the TV signal?

Tags: electrical, tv-antenna

I have an antenna tv and every time I turn on my computer, it knocks out the signal to my tv. I have tried plugging the computer in to different areas in my house and buying a booster for the antenna signal.

I have 20 amp fuses in my house for the electricity and the wiring was just updated 5 years ago. What can I do to fix it? Could it be my fuses?

Comment: So, you are saying no matter where your computer is in the house, when you turn it on you lose the antenna signal to your TV? So you can't get any channels while the computer is on? If your TV and computer both stay powered it is not your fuses.

Comment: There's a warning on every piece of electronics you buy that while it's designed to minimize interference, resolving any that does arise is the buyer's problem. Someone has to figure out whether the noise is radio or on the power wires, what specific component in the PC is causing it (fan, power supply, badly shielded case, ...) and determine whether and how it can be fixed. If this is a laptop, does it interfere when running from battery?

Comment: Is the antenna grounded? Is cable from the antenna grounded?

Comment: This isn't your fuses.  However: Is your computer a desktop or a laptop? If it's a laptop, does it interfere when running on battery, or only when running on AC power?

Comment: the antenna is grounded and yes they both stay on just there is no signal it is a desk top my air mattres knocks out the signal as well when i use it it has a built in pump

Comment: So you're saying the air mattress pump knocks the TV signal out *while it is running*?

Comment: yes the air mattress pump does it as well

Comment: Why kind of antenna are we talking about? Indoor, outdoor? Do all stations go out or just the distant ones?

Comment: There are different levels of quality in TV station tuners ( The  tuner inside the television )   and sadly many  manufacturers go the cheap route because they assume you’re going to have cable or satellite. But that being said there are televisions that have very good tuners Installed. maybe you could borrow a television or two from some friends and test to see if the same problem occurs for  different tuners.

Answer (score 3):

Your TV, sadly, has what is referred to as a *susceptibility* problem -- it's vulnerable to being confused by electromagnetic trash generated by other gizmos, like air pumps and desktop PCs.  From the nature of the interfering devices, it sounds like the electromagnetic trash is being carried from your PC and air pump to your TV via the power lines.

My recommendation is to plug your TV into a high-end surge suppressor with built-in EMI filtering circuitry (such as a Tripp Lite Isobar or Isotel) -- this will reduce the amount of trash that gets into your TV, and hopefully make it so you can watch TV with the computer on.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I was having this issue and found the problem if your using a Leaf style antenna. I tried lots of things but sometimes you just gotta Keep it simple.

I wrapped tin foil around the antenna part facing in. That's it. Every single problem disappeared. Instantly.

Might even be boosting things a bit.

Just posting this in here since it was the first google result I got.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Every time I switched on the PC the television signal turned to pixellated soup. In desperation, I wrapped ordinary tin foil - the sort you use for cooking - around the antenna lead head where it plugs into the wall socket and 99% of the problem cleared up. I'll just have to assume that the foil deflects the electromagnetic soup and allows the set to receive the signal. And yes, before I did this, I invested in a signal booster and it didn't make a bit of difference - but the foil did.

Answer (score 0):

Blocking the antenna didn't work for me but covering the back of my desktop CPU did work. Still gets fuzzy every once in awhile but went from not getting any signal to getting 95% signal. I just put double layer tin foil on the back side of the CPU tower. Made an immediate difference

Comment: I'd check the back of your PC to make sure you don't have any missing expansion card slot covers and that the thin metal EMI gasket/shield piece around the on-motherboard ports is correctly fitted/seated -- if you are missing either of those pieces, then RF trash can leak out of the PC case via the resulting hole